# plotting three column variables in a 2D plane in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a file with data arranged in three columns. I am trying to make 2D contour plot of these values, where the values in the third column (Z) is projected on the space formed by values in the first (X) and second column (Y). But usual matlab commands like 'contour' and 'imagesc' take the Z-values in the matrix format. Is there a way out in Matlab to plot these values in a 2D-plane?

Comment: It depends how the data is arranged. Do you need an interpolation inbetween?

Comment: Contour usually works with two vectors (X and Y) and a matrix (Z). So for each elements of the two vectors (X(i) , Y(i)), there should be a value in the matrix (Z(i,j)). Thus the size of the matrix Z should be equal to the size of the first vector (X) multiplied by the size of the second vector (Y). What is the data you are working with? and Why do you need a contour?

Comment: If you want to use contour you need to interpolate your `Z` data to the grid generated by `[X,Y]=meshgrid(X,Y)`. Without interpolation you don't have too much options. What about [`scatter`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Contour usually works with two vectors (X and Y) and a matrix (Z). So for each elements of the two vectors (X(i) , Y(i)), there should be a value in the matrix (Z(i,j)). Thus the size of the matrix Z should be equal to the size of the first vector (X) multiplied by the size of the second vector (Y).

if the x,y,z have the same size then you can do something like this:

```
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(x,y,z);
contour(X,Y,Z)
```

on the other hand if you manage to make the sizes correct then you can do something like this example:

```
x = linspace(-2*pi,2*pi);
y = linspace(0,4*pi);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = sin(X)+cos(Y);

figure
contour(X,Y,Z)
```